# ReactNative: is it possible to avoid storing all dependencies in node_modules subfolder

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native, node-modules

I'm quite new to ReactNative so sorry if it's obvious, but..

Each RN project init-ed via CLI has a large number of node modules stored in project_root/node_modules. Not that I would mind, but if you have several projects it seems redundant and takes up time/space to move it to the source versioning system.

Wouldn't it be possible to retrieve all these same modules from the general node_modules on the machine instead ?

Comment: Depending on your VCS, you should configure it to ignore `node_modules` folder (for example for Git it is `.gitignore` file) and only keep the file `package.json`. Anyone who has that `package.json` can then fetch the same dependencies on their machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never want to store dependencies nested in `node_modules` in your source control... it defeats the whole purpose of versioning and dependencies in general. Your `package.json` file will specify the versions so when you run `npm install` it knows exactly which dependencies to grab.

**As an alternative, [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) is an up and rising package client that Facebook developed** that does a much better job of caching your packages locally so that way if multiple projects reuse the same depencencies, it will still satisfy the need to keep them in `node_modules` but doesn't need to perform http requests for each one.

Yarn doesn't replace NPM as a package registry, just a better client to download, maintain, and cache those packages.

Yarn also adds a `yarn.lock` file (similar to Ruby's Gemfile.lock) that allows you to lock in the specific versions used in your app, regardles of the `package.json`. [This file can be stored in version control](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/yarn-lock#toc-check-into-source-control), which is probably what you were wanting to achieve by saving the `node_modules` in version control.

Some good reads...

- [Yarn vs NPM](https://www.sitepoint.com/yarn-vs-npm/)
- [Scotch.io Yarn Tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/yarn-package-manager-an-improvement-over-npm)
- [Why I'm working on Yarn](http://yehudakatz.com/2016/10/11/im-excited-to-work-on-yarn-the-new-js-package-manager-2/) (Yehuda Katz)

Answer (score 0):

I would echo Brad's answer: Don't put `node_modules` in version control. `npm install` will install the correct versions from the `package.json`. Just put `package.json` in version control, not `node_modules`.

However, if you still want to save disk space, you can install some of your dependencies in a general `node_modules` folder by using the `link` option:

```
npm config set link true -g
```

You can read more about `link` here: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#link.

Note that you *must not* include `node_modules` in your version control when using this option since `npm` will put symlinks to the globally installed packages in `node_modules`. The global install location varies from machine to machine, so if `node_modules` is in version control, it may link to non-existent locations.